# Powershell DSC Hangs

Tags: windows, powershell, scripting

So here's my issue, I am trying to use PS Dsc to install some basic packages, but whenever I try and run my script it looks like it starts but never finishes. I try to pass the `-Force` parameter as recommended but it seems like it's just stacking operations and these processes just keep getting stuck.

Here is my script

```
Configuration WebServer {

# Import the module that contains the resources we're using.
 Import-DscResource -ModuleName PsDesiredStateConfiguration

 Node "localhost" {

    Package InstallAspNetWebPages2
    {
        Ensure = "Present"
        Path = 
"C:\Users\jryter\Documents\WebServerInstalls\AspNetWebPages2Setup.exe"
        Name = "Microsoft ASP.NET Web Pages 2 Runtime"
        ProductID = "EA63C5C1-EBBC-477C-9CC7-41454DDFAFF2"
    }

 }

}


WebServer -OutputPath "C:\DscConfiguration"

Start-DscConfiguration -Wait -Force -verbose -Path "C:\DscConfiguration"
```

the current LCM state is it's performing a consistency check. 
I tried following this link --> 
https://powershell.org/forums/topic/stop-dsc-configuration-which-is-runningstuck/

but to no avail....

is there some base configuration that I missed to run this stuff properly? Has anyone had this issue?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DSC probably started the exe and it just sits there waiting for your input. You need to add arguments for silent install.

```
Package InstallAspNetWebPages2
{
    Ensure = "Present"
    Path = "path\file.exe"
    Name = "Microsoft ASP.NET Web Pages 2 Runtime"
    ProductID = "EA63C5C1-EBBC-477C-9CC7-41454DDFAFF2"
    Arguments   = "/silent" or "/quiet"
}
```

I don't know what's the proper argument for this exe

Comment: Gave this a shot but not seeing any results. I tried passing --> `Arguments   = "/i /q /norestart" ` but it doesn't look like it's doing anything. I can't seem to find any formal documentation on powershell package resource arguments either.

Comment: has nothing to do with powershell dsc. find how to install this particular file silently and pass these arguments to the dsc.

Comment: So in this case, the argument for silent install is `/q`. However, since my DSC state was already 'hanging' I needed to clear out everything from DSC performing the following actions 
`#Remove all mof files (pending,current,backup,MetaConfig.mof,caches,etc)
rm C:\windows\system32\Configuration\*.mof*
#Kill the LCM/DSC processes
gps wmi* | ? {$_.modules.ModuleName -like "*DSC*"} | stop-process -force`. I will give you correct answer though, since because of the silent argument I was actually able to install after I killed the process.